# Removing FireSALE from the URI - Routing issue

Tags: routes, pyrocms

I have installed the module `FireSALE` in `PyroCMS`.

I want to remove the "**FireSale**" from the URI or change it to a custom string if possible.
i.e

```
http://mydomain.com/firesale/cart
```

to

```
http://mydomain.com/cart
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be able to accomplish it in the main routes.php (system/cms/config/routes.php

The best way to do it without running into conflicts (such as other modules uri like domain.com/blog etc) is to place something like the below code in your routes.php

```
$route['category/(order|layout)/([0-9]+)'] = 'firesale/front_category/$1/$2';
$route['category(:any)']                   = 'firesale/front_category/index$1';
$route['product(:any)']                    = 'firesale/front_product/index$1';
$route['search(:any)?']                    = 'firesale_search/search/index$1';
$route['cart(:any)?']                      = 'firesale/cart$1';
```

Also change your default controller from pages to firesale (optional)

Answer (score 0):

The current acceptable method of doing this is using routes.
An alternative to using routes, you can actually rename your module. It can be done using a script. This effectively changes the path of the module to your desired path.
e.g.: It can be used to rename "blog" to "articles".

Linux:
https://gist.github.com/3680107

OS X:
https://gist.github.com/3949038